# reading from file into 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I have to read data from a file like this:

```
4
192 48 206 37 56
123 35 321 21 41
251 42 442 32 33
```

the first number is the total number of candidates(columns) and i need to store that value for other use. Then i need to read the rest of the data into a 2D array. I updated my code with what i have now but it still not working. I keep getting the error 
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

```
 public static int readData(int[][] table, Scanner in)throws IOException
{
System.out.println("Please enter the file name: ");
 String location = in.next();
 Scanner fin = new Scanner(new FileReader(location));
 int candidates = fin.nextInt();
 fin.nextLine();
for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
  for (int column = 0; column < candidates; column++) {
    String line = fin.nextLine();
    fin.nextLine();
    String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
    String token = tokens[column];
    table[row][column] = Integer.parseInt(token);
  }
}
fin.close();
return candidates;
}

}
```

Comment: Define "completely not working". What is happening? Does a waffle come out of the screen? First of all, you're ignoring `candidates`. Second, you are simply reading the first line: `fin.nextLine();` should be in each iteration.

Comment: getting the error
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" after i enter the filename

Comment: how am i ignoring candidates? I don't understand.

Comment: You are hard-coding 5 in your loops instead of parsing `candidates` which is the number of expected lines to read. Then, you are not reading in each iteration.

Comment: ahh yea i see thanks.

Comment: I updated it to what i have now but I am still having trouble.

Comment: You should be calling `fin.nextLine();` after your inner loop ends, but inside your outer loop.

Comment: I tried adding that but i still get the no line found error

Comment: You have an outer loop of 5, an inner loop of 4, for a total iteration count of 20. You call `nextLine` twice in the inner loop, for a total call count of 40. There are only 3 lines in the input, so on the 4th of 40 calls you error out!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, your main task is to extract **integer** values from file and put it into the 2D array.

I would recommend you refering to the Scanner API Reference on Oracle website:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

You can find there, that there are some more suitable methods for your task:

1. [nextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) - used to get integer value directly from file
2. [hasNextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine()) - used to determine if there is next line of input

Assuming, that `candidates` is the *number of columns*, it should be treated as integer, not string:

```
int candidates = fin.nextInt();
```

With use of mentioned Scanner methods, getting `String` values from file won't be needed anymore, so `line` and `numbers` variables may be completely removed from source code.

With use of `hasNextLine()` method, you can be sure, that file will be read till its end:

```
int row = 0;
while(fin.hasNextLine()) {                         //while file has more lines
    for(int col = 0; col < candidates; j++) {      //for 'candidates' number of columns
        table[row][col] = fin.nextInt();           //read next integer value and put into table
    }
    row++;                                         //increment row number
}
```

Please remember, that **Java arrays are not dynamically scalable**.

Your 2D array - `table` should be initialized with exact size of data to be put inside.

In your current example you don't know the number of input rows until the end of file, so proper initialization of array may require additional operations.

Comment: helped me a ton dude works perfectly now thanks for the help

Comment: Happy to hear :) 
Cheers!