# How to Read a CSV file into a 2D array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a huge .csv file. It has about 130,000 rows and 13 columns. I need to create a bunch of graphs using that data in a web app. I am very new to JavaScript. Can anyone help me reading this huge file and store the data into a 2D array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reading from file into 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35757842/reading-from-file-into-2d-array)

Comment: Try using a library, makes things easier, `https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv`

Comment: I tried that. But my file is huge and that library does not support over 10,000 rows. :(

Comment: @beefoak That's Java and I am trying to do in JavaScript

Comment: Are you working on a node app?? @PratikPatel

Comment: Yes I am @AbhishekKumawat

Comment: There are lots of packages on npm, have you tried any?? Example `https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv`

Comment: I will try those. thank you. @AbhishekKumawat

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this lib
http://c2fo.io/fast-csv
or 
https://www.papaparse.com/

this libs use streams, and you can use huge file and modify each line

Comment: I have tried fast-csv. but it gives a compiler error, saying - createReadFile is not a function

Comment: Do you want load csv to client side? It's bad idea. You need send it to backend and parse there

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a node app, try looking for packages on npm,

https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=csv

Else, you might want to take a look at the following link for core javascript code:

[How to read data From *.CSV file using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431268/how-to-read-data-from-csv-file-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you:

```
 <head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

// Reading csv data from file using get ou post or whateven protocol
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
            var lines = processData(data);
            console.log(lines);
        }
    });
});

// Passing csv data direct from text string
csv = "heading1,heading2,heading3,heading4,heading5\nvalue1_1,value2_1,value3_1,value4_1,value5_1\nvalue1_2,value2_2,value3_2,value4_2,value5_2";
var lines = processData(data);
console.log(lines);


function processData(allText) {
    var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    var headers = allTextLines[0].split(',');
    var lines = [];

    for (var i=1; i<allTextLines.length; i++) {
        var data = allTextLines[i].split(',');
        if (data.length == headers.length) {

            var tarr = [];
            for (var j=0; j<headers.length; j++) {
                tarr.push(data[j]);
            }
            lines.push(tarr);
        }
    }
    return lines;
}
 </head>
```

Comment: Note: this code needs jquery to make an ajax request or you can change it to a pure javascript ajax request.

Comment: Failed to compile.

./src/App.js
  Line 4:  '$' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 5:  '$' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: you need tou include jquery lebrary before call your code

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>